# What do the two bedroom bell-pull switches in the Boyles' mansion do?

Tags: dishonored

In Dishonoured, in the mission where:

> You have to kill/kidnap one of the three Lady Boyles from a masked ball in their mansion you can sneak upstairs to the bedrooms to search for clues as to which one you need to neutralise.

In two of the three bedrooms there's a bell-pull switch.

What effect does pulling one or both of them have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It opens a hidden hatch above the shelves, giving access to a secret area.

Comment: It basically just lets you move between the first two sister's rooms without being detected. Also acts as a hiding spot guards literally can never get to.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk You need a secret hideyhole to move around without being detected? *Pffft*, you're playing it wrong ;)

Comment: I found that attic area but I didn't realise that the bell-pull is what opened it. Cheers :-)